# Dynamically create Tensor at runtime in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to create a Input Tensor for a model at runtime . At each time the size of the image differs. How would i create a tensor at runtime and attach to the default graph. ?

Comment: you can use placeholder with no shape and feed your image into that placeholder

Comment: I actually need to change the input Tensor in a loop and in each iteration having a different size.

Comment: that's fine, placeholder can accept a different shape tensor through feed dict during each run call